# Can we queue BackGroundWorker objects

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Is there a way in which we can queue Background workers.

Scenario : We have two BackgroundWorker objects, BGW1 & BGW2.

Can I run them sequentially, say if BGW1 is running and an event calls BGW2. can I queue it with BGW1. Similarly if BGW1 has completed its run ; and BGW2 is running I should be able to queue BGW1 and wait until BGW2 has completed its run.

Comment: yout could start the seconds worker in the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted`event and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

If they have to run after each other one could use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to start the next one and vice versa. An if clause could be used to terminate the cycling calls.
Here is a class that could accomplish that:

```
public class BGWQue
{
    public BackgroundWorker Worker_1 { get; set; }
    public BackgroundWorker Worker_2 { get; set; }
    bool endWorkerLoop = false;

    public BGWQue()
    {
        this.Worker_1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.Worker_1.DoWork += Worker_1_DoWork;
        this.Worker_1.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_1_RunWorkerCompleted;

        this.Worker_2 = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.Worker_2.DoWork += Worker_2_DoWork;
        this.Worker_2.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_2_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }


    void Worker_1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        job_1();
    }

    void Worker_1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // condition to end the cycle
        if (!endWorkerLoop)
        {
            this.Worker_2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }


    void Worker_2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        job_2();
    }

    void Worker_2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // condition to end the cycle
        if (!endWorkerLoop)
        {
            this.Worker_1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    public void startWorkers()
    {
        this.Worker_1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    // fictional jobs for the workers
    public void job_1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    public void job_2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```